# Recover a Windows partition after installing Ubuntu on dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I've just installed Ubuntu on my laptop on dual boot and now I can't start up on Windows 7, I don't have the GRUB menu that allows me to choose an OS.

When installing Ubuntu, I reducted my Windows partition to make more free disk space in order to create Ubuntu's partitions. I think it corrupted my Windows partition.

Can you help me recover my Windows partition ? Even if it means losing Ubuntu because I don't mind reinstalling it, whereas it would be very long to me to reinstall and setup Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Boot-Repair**, a tool which fixes this kind of problem.

You just have to boot in Ubuntu and type the following in a terminal to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Once the program is open, just click *"Recommended repair"* and cross your fingers!

If you need any further information, you can take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran the "Recommanded repair", which guided me through installing GRUB on every 3 partitions I have. Now I have GRUB when booting my laptop, but there is no Windows option, I can only choose "Ubuntu", "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and "System setup". Here is the Pastebin that was generated by Boot-Repair : http://paste.ubuntu.com/12015136/

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, then `sudo grub-install` and finally `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but when I try `sudo grub-install` i says `grub-install : error : Install device isn't specified`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't display Windows 7 on GRUB menu :/

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than 4 primary partitions windows wont boot I would consider checking on your windows partitions as some of them may be unnecessary from certain install disks. some companies like HP use a few too many for my liking and I ended up removing one of their partitions created on my win 7 install so that I could install ubuntu as dual boot. This may require a little more research on your part to determine what you can remove.